# RTL Confirm and Alert in Javascript

Tags: javascript, internationalization

Can you make a `confirm` or `alert` show its message RTL and right-aligned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Programmatically no, but the user's culture setting for their machine should determine which way it's presented, at least in all current browsers. I'm not aware of a comprehensive "who supports it" list though.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding this at the beginning of your message:
"\u200f\u200f"

for example:

```
alert("\u200f\u200f"+ message);
```

or

```
confirm("\u200f\u200f"+ message);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the `<html>`tag, set direction to RTL like this `<html dir="rtl">`

You may also do it with javascript as shown below:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].setAttribute("dir","rtl");
```