# Alert with several option with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want make a alert that after click on button delete ask `did you want delete this?` with two options: `ok` and `cancel`. If user clicks on `ok` the value is deleted. If the user clicks on `cancel` don't delete the value.

Like this in this site:

[image: Stackoverflow confirmation dialog for post deletion vote]

How to do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<a href="#" id="delete">Delete</a>

$('#delete').click(function() {
   if (confirm('Do you want to delete this item?')) {
      // do delete item
   }
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/hP2Dz/4/

Comment: Yep, forgot to escape `'` symbol in `wan\'t`. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/hP2Dz/4/

Comment: Did can use from `direction: rtl;` for alert and change value `ok` and `cancel`?

Comment: This is not html dialog so you can't change buttons caption. About first question - here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845541/rtl-comfirm-and-alert-in-javascript

Comment: nice, never know can be this simple.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to style your alert, check this plugin: [jquery-alert-dialogs](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/). It's very easy to use.

```
jAlert('This is a custom alert box', 'Alert Dialog');

jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
     jAlert('Confirmed: ' + r, 'Confirmation Results');
});

jPrompt('Type something:', 'Prefilled value', 'Prompt Dialog', function(r) {
    if( r ) alert('You entered ' + r);
});
```

---

**UPDATE:**  the oficial site is currently offline. [here is another source](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo)

Comment: Site is currently down, but I did find this: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, that type of box is `confirm`, not `alert`.  `confirm` returns a boolean, representing whether the user responded positively or negatively to the prompt (i.e. clicking `OK` results in `true` being returned, whereas clicking `cancel` results in `false` being returned).  This is applicable to jQuery, but also in JavaScript more broadly.  You can say something like:

```
var shouldDelete = confirm("Do you want to delete?");
if (shouldDelete) {
  // the user wants to delete
} else {
  // the user does not want to delete
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might not be jquery but is the simple principle that you could use

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_confirm()
{
var r=confirm("vote ");
if (r==true)
  {
  alert("ok delete"); //you can add your jquery here
  }
else
  {
  alert(" Cancel! dont delete"); //you can add your jquery here
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="show_confirm()" value="Vote to delete?" /> <!-- can be changed to object binding with jquery-->

</body>
</html>Vot
```

Comment: `var r=confirm("vote "); if (r==true)` == `if(confirm("vote"))`