# How to text-align right a javascript ALERT?

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8

I am trying to right align some text in a javascript alert box. It is an Israeli client so the context is in hebrew and should be right aligned.

```
alert("הצעת חוק פרטית לאסור על\n מוסדות המדינה לשלם לספקים תמורת טובין ושירותים בתשלומים דחויים");
```

It does look ok in FireFox and Chrome, but not in IE9.

ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RTL Confirm and Alert in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845541/rtl-comfirm-and-alert-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use some alternative javascript alerts like [Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/) or similar. Its style can easily be configured to suite your needs and most of them are cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version of IE9 which is in a language that is based on right aligned text, the text will be right-aligned in IE9 (native) windows. Are you sure you're testing with a hebrew version of IE9? Keep in mind, unlike FF and Chrome, IE9 UI language == Windows language.